# Determine whether an AutomationElement is visible

Tags: c#, ui-automation, automationelement

Is there any way to determine if an AutomationElement is visible to the user?

Both ClickablePoint and IsOffcreen have exceptions where they show/hide (un)desired elements.

Eg. when I have a fullscreen window the desktop icons have no ClickablePoint but are not offscreen but some items in the menubar of the fullscreen application that are clearly visible are also not clickable.

So if I go by ClickablePoint the desktop icons are hidden but the menu items are missing and if I go by Offscreen, the menu items are visible but the desktop items are also visible.

Comment: are you looking for a particular element (i.e. button, icon, etc), or just a generic is visible method.  I've found that some items may need special handling in regard to is visible.

Comment: I need a general one. If I need to implement this per item so it be.

Comment: have you came up with a solution?